# Word document parsed with insertOOXML replaces images on iPad only

Tags: ipad, ms-word, office-js

I am working on an Office-js add-in that uploads the body of the document as OOXML, does some processing, and then "sets" the body of the original document to the processed one from our server using insertOOXML.

The processing inserts inline images around certain blocks of text. When the add-in is tested on Mac and Windows it works flawlessly. On the iPad however, the images look correct initially but if the document is saved and reopened all of the images are changed to match the first image. If the document is first processed on Mac then sent to the iPad, this is the case as well. The images look correct at first but after saving and quitting the images all match the first image.

I have retrieved the document from the server directly and have not been able to recreate this issue, which makes me think it is related to how the document's body is set.

A little more detail on our implementation: The document is uploaded as OOXML and is treated as a docx file. I'm reasonably sure that the processing on the server is bug free because we use the same code to process docx files elsewhere without issue. To set the document, it is requested in flatOPC and set like so:

```
Word.run(function (context) {
    var body = context.document.body;
    body.insertOoxml(docXML, Word.InsertLocation.replace);
    return context.sync()
});
```

Where docXML is the document in flatOpc format.

Is anyone else having a similar issue? Otherwise is this an issue with our code, insertOoxml, or Word on the iPad?